# subscribe is not a function error thrown when trying to use JSON file in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-services

I'm trying to import a `JSON` file into my service and am receiving this error

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this._qs.getBasicInfo(...).subscribe is not a function(…)

As of right now my `service` file looks like this

```
@Injectable()

export class QuestionService {

BasicInfoData: Observable<any>;

constructor(private http: Http){}

getBasicInfo() {
    this.BasicInfoData = this.http.get('app/questionnaire/questions.json').map(res =>
    res.json()).subscribe(data => this.BasicInfoData = data ) as Observable<any>

    return this.BasicInfoData;
    }

}
```

and my `component` looks like this

```
@Component({

    moduleId    : module.id,
    selector    : 'questionnaire-page',
    templateUrl : './questionnaire.component.html',
    providers   : [ QuestionService ]
})

export class QuestionnairePage implements OnInit, OnChanges {

    BasicInfo: Observable<any>;

    constructor(private _qs: QuestionService, private fbuild: FormBuilder) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this._qs.getBasicInfo().subscribe( data => this.BasicInfo = data );
     console.log(this.BasicInfo);
    }

}
```

prior to trying to call the data from my service I had it working perfectly fine calling it directly into the `ngOnInit()` of my `component` like this

```
this.http.get('app/questionnaire/questions.json').subscribe(res => {
     this.Questions = res.json()
     console.log(this.Questions);
});
```

I started out trying to use this same thing and as I read, I added the `Observable`.  I came across another post about `RXJS` saying their problem was subscribing directly to the data before it got there and their fix was to use `.map()` first then subscribe to that.  It changed my error from an `undefined` error to the one I'm getting now so I figured that was a step in the right direction.  I've been back and forth trying all sorts of things and it either creates another error indicating it breaks before this point or I just get the same error from the same snip of code.  Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code returns a `Subscription`

```
getBasicInfo() {
    this.BasicInfoData = this.http.get('app/questionnaire/questions.json').map(res =>
    res.json()).subscribe(data => this.BasicInfo = data ) as Observable<any>

    return this.BasicInfoData;
    }
}
```

`subscribe` is a method of `Observable` not of `Subscription`.
What you want is probably

```
getBasicInfo() {
    return this.http.get('app/questionnaire/questions.json')
    .map(res => res.json());
}
```

this way an `Observable` is returned which can be subscribed to.

Comment: I'm getting another error now saying `Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined(…)`

Comment: I guess you should add import of `map` operator. In the file where you use `.map` like `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';`

Comment: I also removed the line `map(data => this.BasicInfoData = data)`. It doesn't really make sense, especially with `BasicInfoData: Observable<any>;`

Comment: it's occurring in line 23 of the JS file, which is where the subscription is.

Comment: What subscription? this one `ngOnInit() {
        this._qs.getBasicInfo().subscribe(` or a different one?

Comment: Can't imagine. Perhaps you omitted the `return` in `getBasicInfo()`

Comment: ok I just updated the code in the service to what you have, and I'm not getting any errors, but I'm still getting `undefined` in the `console.log()`

Comment: maybe it's something with the path to my `json` file.

Comment: There is no way to get the result of an async call at that place, you need to change the code to `this._qs.getBasicInfo().subscribe( data => {this.BasicInfo = data; console.log(this.Questions);});`. `data => {this.BasicInfo = data; console.log(this.Questions)` is a function (callback) that you pass to `subscribe(...)` for the `Observable` to call it when eventually data arrives. `ngOnInit` won't wait for that to happen, it will continue executing and the callback will be called sometimes (much) later.